# .NET Core 1.0 app won't run on .NET Core 1.1 system

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a program that I'm trying to migrate over to .NET Standard/Core.  The command line interface to the library is built with a target framework of netcoreapp1.0.  I tried sending this to a tester (with a different OS) who only had .NET Core 1.1 installed.  The program won't run, and gives the error:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.
- Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
- The following versions are installed:
  1.1.0
- Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.
```

Is this expected?  As I understood it, each Core/Standard version was a strict superset of the prior one.  As such, I expected a program that targeted 1.0 would still run on a system with 1.1, rather than having to multi-target every installation version.

More generally, how can I set things up so that I don't have to worry about a user coming along later with only a newer version of .NET Core being unable to run the program?

Comment: `1.1.0` != `1.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand a few more concepts.

1. A .NET Core app becomes self-contained if you use `dotnet publish` properly. Then on a target machine that has no .NET Core installed (or not the version it builds against) the app can run without problems. Based on your description, you probably forget to do so or you are not trying to publish this app.
2. If your intention is just to move your .NET Core 1.0.1 based code to another machine and that machine only has 1.1.0 installed, well, you should be able to run `dotnet-install` script to install the required runtime,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-install-script

Since you are using Visual Studio 2017 RC already, you should know that .NET Core 1.0.x now should be 1.0.3. Support for 1.0.0-1.0.2 have expired.

Comment: 1.0.1 was the default for preview4 tooling, which is the only version of the SDK to support .csproj projects at this time (preview3 isn't available anymore).  Fortunately I've found that preview4 can still build 1.1.0 (as well as 1.0.3, etc, by using the right nuget package), and through a number of experiments with that I've decided to just publish the program as 1.1.  It doesn't solve the problem of "Will it run when 1.2 is released, and that's the only version installed on a target machine?", though, but I can put it off for now.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a global.json. Add one to your project so the application knows to boot with the 1.0.0 runtime and not 1.1.

Comment: Sort of sounds like what I need, but not quite.  I'm building in VS 2017 (should have mentioned that), which means I'm using .csproj/msbuild, not project.json/global.json. It *is* generating a [projectname].runtimeconfig.json in the publish directory that specifies the version to run, and it works locally with 1.0.0/1.0.1/1.0.2/1.0.3, but not on 1.0.4 (so, as expected for the 1.0 line).  It won't run a target 1.0.4 on 1.1.0, either, though.

Comment: @dsmith I haven't tested it, but I am fairly sure that even in VS2017 and the csproj format, global.json is still used to specify the SDK version. global.json and project.json are not the same thing.

Comment: True, but the global.json file is to specify which set of build tools to use, not any of the runtime stuff.  Since I have .csproj projects, the only valid tools for me are the preview4 ones, which only support .csproj (preview3 would also have worked, but I don't have any of that version installed).  All the preview2 tools only support project.json, which means they won't work at all.  Since those are the only options I have, there's nothing I can change in global.json that would make a difference.  Was still useful to have dug into, though.